# Parent Class fetched multiple times in Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I've got 2 classes with OneToMany mapping.
There is a Question class and an Answer class. For every question there are 4 answers written in the table. There are 10 Question rows and corresponding 40 answer rows in the tables
Now when I try to fetch the List it gives me 40 Question(s) instead of 10 with 4 duplicates for each Question.

Here is my Question class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "QUESTIONS")
public class Question implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "QUES_ID_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "QUES_ID_SEQ", sequenceName = "QUES_ID_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "QUESTION_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(length = 255)
    private String question;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Answer.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Cascade(CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE)
    @JoinTable(name = "QNA",
                joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "QUESTION_ID"),
                inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ANSWER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ANSWER_ID"))
    private List<Answer> answers;

    public Question() {}

// getters and setters ...
}
```

Here is my Answer class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ANSWERS")
public class Answer implements Serializable{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ANS_ID_SEQ")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "ANS_ID_SEQ", sequenceName = "ANS_ID_SEQ")
    @Column(name = "ANSWER_ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(length = 255)
    private String answer;

    private boolean correct;

    public Answer() {}

// getters and setters ...
}
```

I'm fetching the Questions like this:

```
    @Transactional
    public List<Question> retrieveQuestions(){
        Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Question.class);
        return (List<Question>) criteria.list();
    }
```

Comment: Your join is returning a cartesian product (to be expected), so 10 * 4 = 40 - you need a `DISTINCT` query to get back one instance per Question - I'd post a more detailed answer but I haven't used the Criteria API... (Using a Set rather than a List is another option)

Comment: Enable the showing of generated SQL query (hibernate.show_sql true) and see what query gets fired.

Answer (score 3):

Also, I solved the issue using the following piece of code:

```
Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(Question.class);
        return (List<Question>) criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();
```

**Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY** <- This piece of code helps me to get unique Question(s) and also I used **FetchType.EAGER**. It works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

Your mapping is not correct. If you have a one to many association from question to answer why do you have a join table?

The correct mapping for this one to many association would be:

On Answer class:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "question_id")
public Question getQuestion() {
    return question;
}
```

On Question class:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "question", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
public List<Answer> getAnswer() {
    return answers;
}
```

One more thing: for one collection mapping in the Question class is OK to use FetchType.EAGER, but if you map one more collection switch to FetchType.LAZY to avoid fetching a cartezian product.

Comment: Hi dcernahoschi
If I don't use a join table I guess all the question data will be repeated in the database 4 times for all the answers, I guess. So it might lead to more redundancy.

Comment: But, still, why a join table named QNA?

Comment: The only reason for a similar mapping would be an optional one to many association (if for example an answer might have NO question) but is not the case here.

Comment: I agree with dcernahoschi. You don't need additional table in this case.